# Protected Merchant Ships in WWII used for the relocation of Prisoners of War

Tags: prisoners-of-war

What Merchanht ships were declared as "protected" in WWII for the transferred of Prisoners of War, between warring nations

Comment: Are you asking what types of ship were used or are you asking for actual, named examples of the ships that were used?

Comment: What evidence have you found to support the notion that ANY such ships existed. Submarines don't stop and ask for identification papers before firing torpedoes.

Answer (score 3):

There is a book "Mercy Ships: The Untold Story of Prisoner-of-War Exchanges in World War II" which covers this topic.

The two principal ships used were Swedish: *Drottningholm* and the *Gripsholm*.

[image]

These ships were also used to exchange civilian internees. The total amounts of people exchanged amounted to a few 10s of thousands. In the case of soldiers, it was mostly sick or disabled soldiers that were exchanged.